# How does SQS determine where each message should be physically stored?

Tags: scalability, amazon-sqs

This is a question of my curiosity regarding the internal architecture of SQS. I did not seem to find an in-depth intro to its architectural design.

From [this basic architecture doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html), I learned that each message is redundantly stored in multiple SQS servers.

I was wondering how does SQS compute what set of SQS servers should be used to store a given message? Does it just randomly choose a set of servers and then maintain the message_id —> server_list mappings in an index server? Or, maybe the SQS servers are divided into multiple redundant groups, and then SQS computes the hash of each message and then compute the server “index” in each group?

Comment: Are you planning to put this information to practical use, or is this just a question of curiosity?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot A question of curiosity

Comment: While it's an interesting question, the only people who could answer this accurately would be those who work (or worked) for Amazon, and they wouldn't be able to due to confidentiality / non-disclosure agreements.

Answer (score 1):

SQS doesn't provide an API to access a message by ID. So there is no need to map it to a specific server instance given an ID which makes both of your guesses incorrect.